# Equation for minimum/maximum eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is well known that for a hermitian matrix $A$ we have $\lambda_{min}(A)=min{x\ne 0} <x,Ax>/<x,x>$, which we can see be diagonalizing $A$. Now here is my question about the following I stumbled upon while doing homework:

> Let $A,B$ be hermitian positive definite matrices. Then $\lambda_{min}(AB^{-1})=min_{x\ne 0}<AB^{-1}x,x>_{B^{-1}}/<x,x>_{B^{-1}}$ where $<x,y>_{B^{-1}}:=<B^{-1}x,y>$.

I seem to be not able to prove this, so I am starting to doubt its validity. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add "min", then it works:
$$
\begin{split}
\min_{x\neq 0}\frac{\langle AB^{-1}x,x\rangle_{B^{-1}}}{\langle x,x\rangle_{B^{-1}}}
&=
\min_{x\neq 0}\frac{\langle B^{-1}AB^{-1}x,x\rangle}{\langle B^{-1}x,x\rangle}
=
\min_{x\neq 0}\frac{\langle B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}(B^{-1/2}x),(B^{-1/2}x)\rangle}{\langle (B^{-1/2}x),(B^{-1/2}x)\rangle}
\\&=
\min_{y\neq 0}\frac{\langle B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}y,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}=\lambda_{\min}(B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2})=\lambda_{\min}(AB^{-1}).
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot the min. Thank you.

Comment: Why does the last equality hold?

Comment: @fstl Because $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ and $B^{-1}A$ are similar: $B^{1/2}(B^{-1}A)B^{-1/2}=B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$. This also confirms that $\lambda_{\min}(B^{-1}A)$ makes sense (the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A$ are real and, in addition, positive).